# Why bother with a golang repository (e.g. like Artifactory) for private packages, are GONOSUMDB/GOPRIVATE dangerous somehow?

Tags: go

I am working on a private golang project that I consume in another private project.
i'm referencing it using its github repository, which worked after I set the repo in GOPRIVATE (GONOSUMDB also worked).

1. Is my approach ok? is there a reason not to set my private repo to GOPRIVATE or GONOSUMDB do I open myself to consuming bad projects this way?
2. In addition, why should I bother with a go, private repository like Artifactory? does it provide any benefit on top of consuming the private github repo?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try the command `go help private` to read the official advice

Comment: Who suggested using Artifactory for a Go project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than considering an artifact repository as private package repository you should consider them as a cache and package security as second priority.

For go module proxy, sum db, and index, you should only be cautious with the proxy server (https://proxy.golang.org/) since that where golang "store" your source files. Hence golang proxy == artifactory in this case.

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Go+Registry :

....

Remote Go registries which provide proxy and caching functionality for remote Go resources.

....

Comment: @ardhitma so if i'm reading your answer correctly, I see no reason not to consume the private github repo (assuming of course I don't care about the caching benefits), right?

Comment: @RoyCa yes as long as you set GOPRIVATE env var correctly